A book about two people getting sucked into a black hole and finding an entire civilization inside
I don't remember much about it just that there is a black hole are there is a highly advanced civilization living inside it

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art?  What do they do when they arrive?  Do they ever get back, or report back?

Was one of them psychic?

Not much to go on, but vaguely reminiscent of The Architects of Hyperspace by Thomas R. McDonough, which can be borrowed (for free but registration required) from the Internet Archive.

Bit of a stretch but perhaps Peter F Hamilton's Void Trilogy, the eponymous Void being the central black hole of the galaxy.

Pohl's The Annals of the Heechee feature a trip to a black hole and the discovery of a civilization inside:

The Assassins have concealed themselves in a black hole. Broadhead and
the Heechee are trying to find them.


And there's a computer game based on it, Gateway II: Homeworld.
